# How do I load/retrieve an Excel workbook from SharePoint using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, directory

I have code that opens a Excel-template file which is stored on our network drive, fills in the blanks using input from another Excel sheet and saves the now filled in template.

We changed to a SharePoint solution.

How do I open using a URL instead of a local directory?

```vb
Private Sub GenererTestjournaler_Click()`
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Directory As String, TempDirectory As String, NewDirectory As Variant
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'This used to be the directory; Directory = "Z:\Hercules\DEN\2. Sager, Igangværende\Dynamisk ankertabel\Dynamisk ankertabel\Ankertabel\Godkendelsesforsøg_skabelon.xlsm"

    'Now i want this to be the new directory:
    Directory = "https://ncconline.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/HerculesDanmark/DE/Dynamisk%20ankertabel/Ankertabel/Godkendelsesfors%C3%B8g_skabelon.xlsm?d=w35745d48f1984d189336f0e630a03f9a&csf=1&web=1&e=90aXBu"
    TempDirectory = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Documents\Temp_template.xlsm"
            
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill TempDirectory
    On Error GoTo 0

    FSO.copyfile Directory, TempDirectory
    Set wbTemplate = Workbooks.Open(TempDirectory)

' And so on...
```

I get

> "Run time error '76' path not found.

I guess its not loading the URL correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Open the workbook in Excel using the URL, then save it to the Temp location.

You can't use FSO/Dir to work with http folders/files.

```vb
Private Sub GenererTestjournaler_Click()

    Const TEMPL_URL As String = "https://ncconline.sharepoint.com/sites/HerculesDanmark/" & _
                 "DE/Dynamisk%20ankertabel/Ankertabel/Godkendelsesfors%C3%B8g_skabelon.xlsm"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim TempName As String
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(TEMPL_URL)
    
    TempName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Documents\Temp_template.xlsm"

    On Error Resume Next
    Kill TempName
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'can use this instead of Kill
    wb.SaveAs TempName
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True  'in place of Kill
    
    '...
    '...

End Sub
```